# Calculate product restocks

Tags: python

Read the current inventory from a file.  Either adjust inventory based on orders or generate a purchase of new inventory.  When a product goes below a certain point, it will be asked to calculate it and then restock it to a target point. I am trying to make it more efficient, such as making it shorter.

```
check = 0 
GTINCODE = [] 
PRODUCTDESCRIPTION = [] 
PRICES = [] 
CURRENTSTOCK = [] 
REORDERLEVEL = [] 
TARGETLEVEL = [] 
RESTOCKORDER = [] 
TARGETORDER = [] 
c=0 
count = 0 
cfile = "none" 
with open("stockfile.txt", "r") as newstockfile: 
    for row in newstockfile: 
        row = row.strip('\n') 
        split = row.split(",")  
        GTINCODE.append(split[0]) 
        PRODUCTDESCRIPTION.append(split[1]) 
        PRICES.append(split[2]) 
        CURRENTSTOCK.append(int(split[3])) 
        REORDERLEVEL.append(split[4]) 
        TARGETLEVEL.append(split[5]) 
while check == 0: 
        menu = input("Do you want to create an order for items below the stock level[1], order items that are out of stock from the order file[2] or quit[3]") 
        if menu == "1":
            cfile = "no" 
            while c < len(CURRENTSTOCK): 
                if int(CURRENTSTOCK[c]) < int(REORDERLEVEL[c]): 
                    RESTOCKORDER.append(GTINCODE[c]) 
                    TARGETORDER.append(TARGETLEVEL[c]) 
                    count = count + 1 
                    c = c + 1 
                    cfile = "yes" 
                else: 
                    c = c + 1 
            c = 0 
            with open ("Reorderfile.txt","w") as newstockfile:
                print("The reorder file  has been created") 
                for c in range (0, count): 
                            neworderfile.write(str(RESTOCKORDER[c]) + ":" + str(TARGETORDER[c] + "\n")) 
        elif menu == "2": 
          if cfile == "yes": 
            with open ("Reorderfile.txt", "r") as neworderfile: 
                for row in neworderfile: 
                    row = row.strip('\n') 
                    split = row.split(":") 
                    c = 0 
                    while i<len(GTINCODE): 
                        if GTINCODE[c] == split[0]: 
                            CURRENTSTOCK[c] = split[c] 
                            c = c + 1 
                        else:                                       
                            c = c + 1
                with open("stockfile.txt", "w") as newstockfile: 
                    for c in range (0,len(GTINCODE)): 
                        newstockfile.write(str(GTINCODE[i]) + ":" + str(PRODUCTDESCRIPTION[i]) + ":" + str(PRICES[i]) + ":" + str(CURRENTSTOCK[i]) + ":" + str(REORDERLEVEL[i]) + ":" + str(TARGETLEVEL[i]) + "\n") 
                print("The products have been restocked") 
          elif cfile == "no": 
              print("No products are out of stock")
          elif cfile == "none": 
              print("The reorder file has not been created") 
          else: 
              print("Error") 
        elif menu == "3": 
            check = 1 
            print("Goodbye") 
        else: 
            print("Please Try Again")
```

Comment: Note that we all want to make our code more efficient. This title is too general for this site. Try to come up with a title that summarizes what the code does. You should also add some description of what the code accomplishes in the text.

Comment: Have a look at [How to ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what a good question needs and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The process for asking for deletion of an answered question is described in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/213556

Comment: as outlined in the given answer: the while-loop: `while i<len(GTINCODE):` is an infinite loop because i is never modified

Answer (score 2):

You might try fixing this infinite loop. **i** does not change in the loop body.

```
                while i<len(GTINCODE): 
                    if GTINCODE[c] == split[0]: 
                        CURRENTSTOCK[c] = split[c] 
                        c = c + 1 
                    else:                                       
                        c = c + 1
```